# Checkbox is cleaning after searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an application using checkbox options but after doing click on search is cleaning what  checked and starting all checked (is not saving the last checked clicked).

Here the table

```
|people|
  |id|    |name|   |state|
   1       ABC       0
   2       DEF       0  
   3       DEF       1
   4       DEF       1
```

Here the controller:

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @people = Person.find(:all,:conditions=>['state = ?',params[:state] ] )
  end

end
```

Here is the view:

```
 <% form_tag :controller=>"person",:action=>"search" do %>
    Single  <%= check_box_tag "state", "0", params[:state] %>
    Married <%= check_box_tag "state", "1", params[:state] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
 <% end %>

 <% @people.each do |p|  %>
    p.name
    p.state
 <% end %>
```

I tried:

```
    Single  <%= check_box_tag "state", "0", params[:state].to_i %>
    Married <%= check_box_tag "state", "1", params[:state].to_i %>
```

And tried this too:

```
    Single  <%= check_box_tag "state", 0, params[:state].to_i %>
    Married <%= check_box_tag "state", 1, params[:state].to_i %>
```

And finally this:

```
    Single  <%= check_box_tag "state", "0", params[:state] %>
    Married <%= check_box_tag "state", "1", params[:state] %>
```

Everytime do click on SEARCH, the check option is cleaning and isn't saving the checked that I did.

The checkbox isn't saving what I checked after doing SEARCH.

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning? Also, what's the value of the [:state]  params when it reaches the controller?

Comment: Is the number of checkboxes fixed? Or could it vary?

Comment: Well 0 is for "single" and 1 is for "married" there are static values like my condition 0 and 1

Comment: Well, you'd used a collection of radio buttons, since a person can only be married or single not both :p . But your problem is with the displaying, right? I mean, when you submit the params go with their right values, only problem is when the search results rendering occurs, the checks are back to their original state. Am i right?

Comment: What values are you getting for either checkbox when you submit the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for checkbox tag is

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

So in third parameter you have to pass either true or false, depending on your params to check or uncheck the checkbox.

Try this

```
Single  <%= check_box_tag "state", "0", params[:state].to_s == '0' %>
Married <%= check_box_tag "state", "1", params[:state].to_s == '1' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using params[:business] instead of params[:state] thats the whole problem i think?

Comment: Sorry I typed bad , please check again

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to maintain the "check" state of the checkbox, not its value.

Checkboxs submit values 1 when checked or 0 when unchecked. So you'd use a variable to store the value of those params.

Something like this:

Controller

```
@single_check = params[:single]
@married_check = params[:married]
```

Then, at your view, use it like this:

```
<% if @single_check == "1" %>
<%   chk_single = "true" %>
<% else %>
<%   chk_single = "false" %>
<% end %>
<% if @married_check== "1" %>
<%   chk_married = "true" %>
<% else %>
<%   chk_married = "false" %>
<% end %>

Single  <%= check_box_tag "state", 0, :checked=> chk_single %>
Married <%= check_box_tag "state", 1, :checked=> chk_married %>
```

Comment: I tried your code now i'm getting both checked active but is not checking what I checked

Comment: IS not keeping the option that i checked

Comment: Both are showing "checked"? Then it means that the variables both have a value of 1. How do you differentiate from one check to another. I see both of them as been named :state.

Comment: Oscar do you understood my question? I have 2 checkbox when i check the option married and then click on search ,the option married should be checked but is not working.
I tried your code but didn't worked because now everytime do click on SEARCH is always checked

Comment: I did understand your question. Can you try and check what values are the variables (@single/married_check) coming with after the search is submitted?